# ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at C:\flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992], locale en-us)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at C:\flutter. Consider adding C:\flutter\bin to the front of your path.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

1. Go where you installed flutter find and click on bin then cache then dart-sdk then bin. Your location should be `drive:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin` copy the location. It's okay if your location is different from mine which was `C:\flutter` then became `c:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin`
2. Press Windows logo key + s or simply in the search tab type "env"
3. Click on edit the system environment variables
4. Click on environment variables
5. Double-click on the path inside the user variable
6. In case you already added Dart to the path remove it.
7. Click the New button or double-click an empty space and paste there `drive:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin` then click ok 3 times.
8. Close any existing cmd and type flutter doctor -v to get detailed info

The cause of this error is your Dart bin was not in the Flutter directory. This may occur because you installed Dart alone before installing Flutter so your Dart environment path made no path relating to Flutter.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It says there, put your dart-sdk inside C:\flutter\bin (if this folders doesn't exist simply create them) after that update your path to sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had two dart.sdk installations. One at C:\Program Files\dart.sdk
and the second already inside the C:\src\flutter\bin\cache folder.

I deleted the former and it solved the warning issue when running 'flutter doctor' and the application works.

BTW, this is also after updating flutter to 3.16.0.

Answer (score 0):

It basically says your path different from where path normally supposed to be

1. Run cmd as Admin
2. run "where dart"
3. if your dart path is different from flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin (if u have too many dart path)
4. delete different path dart files
5. Run cmd and type "flutter doctor"
6. This code will fix the problem.